# Does Testcontainers/LocalStack work with DynamoDb Streams KCL 1.x?

Tags: testcontainers, amazon-dynamodb-streams, localstack, amazon-kcl, testcontainers-junit5

## Problem Statement

I have written a program which utilizes DynamoDb Streams to get notified when an update occurs, this code works fine when using AWS Services but doesn't seem to work utilizing Testcontainers/Localstack for my integration tests.

## What has been done

Tried reverting to older version of testcontainer/localstack

[Read this article](https://dahamposithapathiraja.medium.com/run-amazon-kinesis-client-library-1-x-on-localstack-9a8082dfa9f2), which has a comment at the end which sort of *implies* that KCL 1.x lacks some API's which prevent it from working with Localstack

> However, Kinesis Client Library-1.x has not provided the capability of giving AWS CloudWatch service endpoint URL as a configuration parameter.

I believe the DynamoDb Kinesis adapter uses KCL 1.x internally, so, I don't think I can switch to use KCL 2.x. As an aside, it seems the [DynamoDb Kinesis Adapter](https://github.com/amazon-archives/dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter) has been archived, but Amazon Docs still refer to it and there is nothing in that git repo that indicates why it was archived or what to use instead.

## What Happens?

My program runs fine, I don't see any errors but I also don't get any update information from any shards.

### App Design

Basically the integrations tests start, it creates the required tables in LocalStack (confirmed this is done via AWS CLI), it then places 3 items in the DynamoDb. The Spring Boot Application starts up and reads the data from DynamoDb into a a list. The Integration test then calls the delete endpoint, the delete endpoint simply calls the *CrudRepository.delete* function (implemented via Spring Data DynamoDb). I have confirmed that the actual DynamoDb has gone from 3 elements to 2, with the deleted element removed. The applications cache should get updated when my app gets the updated records from KCL, however; this never happens with TreatContainers/localStack.

The application is using `InitialPositionInStream.LATEST` for reading the shards.

### Application Output

You can see the application starts up and is ready at `13:42:17.468`, the item is "deleted" at `13:42:24.768`. The test then calls *Thread.sleep(1000)* to give KCL time to process any changes and then at `13:42:25.793` the test calls the server to see if the element is still present in the cache, which it is.

Thinking this might be a timing issue, where LocalStack was processing slowly, I added a *@AfterAll* function to my tests which waits for 2 minutes. I utilized `curl` to call the *get* endpoint at `13:44:38.723` and the element still exists, which should have been plenty of time for Localstack to process the updates for the shards.

```
2021-04-05 13:42:07.712  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.d.s.processor.MyKclProcessor    : KCL shard lease table, test-table, exists and is ACTIVE
2021-04-05 13:42:07.770  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.d.s.processor.MyKclProcessor    : KCL shard lease table, kcl-shard-lease-lock, exists and is ACTIVE
2021-04-05 13:42:07.772  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.d.s.processor.MyKclProcessor    : Describing table=test-table
2021-04-05 13:42:07.821  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.d.s.processor.MyKclProcessor    : Got description for table=test-table
2021-04-05 13:42:07.822  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.d.s.processor.MyKclProcessor    : Got stream arn (arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:000000000000:table/test-table/stream/2021-04-05T17:41:21.860) for table=test-table with tableArn=arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:000000000000:table/test-table
2021-04-05 13:42:07.904  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.d.s.processor.MyKclProcessor    : Creating KCL worker
2021-04-05 13:42:07.938  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.a.s.k.leases.impl.LeaseCoordinator     : With failover time 10000 ms and epsilon 25 ms, LeaseCoordinator will renew leases every 3308 ms, takeleases every 20050 ms, process maximum of 2147483647 leases and steal 1 lease(s) at a time.
2021-04-05 13:42:07.941  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.a.s.k.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker  : Shard sync strategy determined as SHARD_END.
2021-04-05 13:42:07.941  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.d.s.processor.MyKclProcessor    : KCL Worker created!
2021-04-05 13:42:07.944  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.k.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker  : Initialization attempt 1
2021-04-05 13:42:07.945  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.k.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker  : Initializing LeaseCoordinator
2021-04-05 13:42:14.525  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.d.s.controller.TestItemController  : *** TestItemController Started ***
2021-04-05 13:42:14.650  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.k.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker  : Syncing Kinesis shard info
2021-04-05 13:42:14.656  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.d.s.DynamoDBStreamsShardSyncer     : syncShardLeases: begin
2021-04-05 13:42:14.656  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.d.s.DynamoDBStreamsShardSyncer     : getShardList: begin
2021-04-05 13:42:14.757  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.d.s.DynamoDBStreamsShardSyncer     : getShardList: done
2021-04-05 13:42:14.779  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.d.s.DynamoDBStreamsShardSyncer     : determineNewLeasesToCreate: begin
2021-04-05 13:42:14.781  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.d.s.DynamoDBStreamsShardSyncer     : determineNewLeasesToCreate: done
2021-04-05 13:42:14.863  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.d.s.DynamoDBStreamsShardSyncer     : cleanupGarbageLeases: begin
2021-04-05 13:42:14.863  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.d.s.DynamoDBStreamsShardSyncer     : cleanupGarbageLeases: done
2021-04-05 13:42:14.863  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.d.s.DynamoDBStreamsShardSyncer     : cleanupLeasesOfFinishedShards: begin
2021-04-05 13:42:14.863  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.d.s.DynamoDBStreamsShardSyncer     : cleanupLeasesOfFinishedShards: done
2021-04-05 13:42:14.863  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.d.s.DynamoDBStreamsShardSyncer     : syncShardLeases: done
2021-04-05 13:42:14.866  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.k.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker  : Starting LeaseCoordinator
2021-04-05 13:42:14.900  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.kinesis.leases.impl.LeaseRenewer   :  Worker Test-application-lMtQuWkZeFmq+ found lease {
  "leaseKey" : "shardId-00000001617600000000-000000000000",
  "leaseOwner" : "Test-application-lMtQuWkZeFmq+",
  "leaseCounter" : 0,
  "concurrencyToken" : null,
  "lastCounterIncrementNanos" : null,
  "checkpoint" : {
    "sequenceNumber" : "LATEST",
    "subSequenceNumber" : 0
  },
  "pendingCheckpoint" : null,
  "ownerSwitchesSinceCheckpoint" : 0,
  "parentShardIds" : [ ]
}
2021-04-05 13:42:14.949  WARN 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.k.metrics.impl.MetricsHelper       : No metrics scope set in thread KCLProcessingThread-0, getMetricsScope returning NullMetricsScope.
2021-04-05 13:42:15.011  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : Worker Test-application-lMtQuWkZeFmq+ saw 1 total leases, 0 expired leases, 1 workers.Unfinished lease target: 1 leases, I have 1 unfinished leases. Finished leases target is 1 and I have 0 finished leases. I will take 0 leases in total.
2021-04-05 13:42:15.011  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : TakeLeases took 0 seconds.
2021-04-05 13:42:16.709  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-04-05 13:42:17.309  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2021-04-05 13:42:17.451  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 50376 (http) with context path ''
2021-04-05 13:42:17.464  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] d.d.r.u.Entity2DynamoDBTableSynchronizer : Checking repository classes with DynamoDB tables test-table for ContextRefreshedEvent
2021-04-05 13:42:17.468  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.dynamodb.DynamoDbStreamsTestApp    : Started DynamoDbStreamsTestApp in 54.763 seconds (JVM running for 77.176)
2021-04-05 13:42:17.872  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.dynamodb.DynamoDbStreamsTestApp    : *** ASK SERVER TO DELETE ITEM 23456 ***
2021-04-05 13:42:17.996  INFO 11414 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-05 13:42:17.996  INFO 11414 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-05 13:42:18.019  INFO 11414 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 23 ms
2021-04-05 13:42:18.068  INFO 11414 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] c.c.u.d.s.controller.TestItemController  : Deleting itemNumber=23456
2021-04-05 13:42:21.670  INFO 11414 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] c.c.u.d.s.controller.TestItemController  : Found inventory item to delete
2021-04-05 13:42:24.768  INFO 11414 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] c.c.u.d.s.controller.TestItemController  : Item deleted
2021-04-05 13:42:24.789  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.dynamodb.DynamoDbStreamsTestApp    : *** SERVER SAYS ITEM 23456 DELETED ***
2021-04-05 13:42:24.954  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.k.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker  : Initialization complete. Starting worker loop.
2021-04-05 13:42:24.970  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.k.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker  : Created new shardConsumer for : ShardInfo [shardId=shardId-00000001617600000000-000000000000, concurrencyToken=b773dd9e-d385-44cd-8189-3cf330b94351, parentShardIds=[], checkpoint={SequenceNumber: LATEST,SubsequenceNumber: 0}]
2021-04-05 13:42:24.972  INFO 11414 --- [dProcessor-0000] c.a.s.k.c.l.w.BlockOnParentShardTask     : No need to block on parents [] of shard shardId-00000001617600000000-000000000000
2021-04-05 13:42:25.793  INFO 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.dynamodb.DynamoDbStreamsTestApp    : *** VERIFY ITEM 23456 WAS DELETED OR NOT ***
2021-04-05 13:42:31.304  INFO 11414 --- [o-auto-1-exec-2] c.c.u.d.s.controller.TestItemController  : Getting itemNumber=23456
2021-04-05 13:42:34.586  INFO 11414 --- [o-auto-1-exec-2] c.c.u.d.s.controller.TestItemController  : Item=TestItem{itemNumber='23456', description='A doo', price=10.99}
2021-04-05 13:42:34.589  INFO 11414 --- [dProcessor-0000] c.a.s.k.c.lib.worker.KinesisDataFetcher  : Initializing shard shardId-00000001617600000000-000000000000 with LATEST
2021-04-05 13:42:34.611 ERROR 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.dynamodb.DynamoDbStreamsTestApp    : *** SERVER STILL HAS ITEM 23456 ***
2021-04-05 13:42:34.663  WARN 11414 --- [    Test worker] c.c.u.dynamodb.DynamoDbStreamsTestApp    : Giving system 2 MINUTES before shut down
2021-04-05 13:42:35.088  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : Worker Test-application-lMtQuWkZeFmq+ saw 1 total leases, 0 expired leases, 1 workers.Unfinished lease target: 1 leases, I have 1 unfinished leases. Finished leases target is 1 and I have 0 finished leases. I will take 0 leases in total.
2021-04-05 13:42:35.088  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : TakeLeases took 0 seconds.
2021-04-05 13:42:55.171  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0001] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : Worker Test-application-lMtQuWkZeFmq+ saw 1 total leases, 0 expired leases, 1 workers.Unfinished lease target: 1 leases, I have 1 unfinished leases. Finished leases target is 1 and I have 0 finished leases. I will take 0 leases in total.
2021-04-05 13:42:55.171  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0001] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : TakeLeases took 0 seconds.
2021-04-05 13:43:08.731  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.k.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker  : Current stream shard assignments: shardId-00000001617600000000-000000000000
2021-04-05 13:43:08.732  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.k.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker  : Sleeping ...
2021-04-05 13:43:15.248  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : Worker Test-application-lMtQuWkZeFmq+ saw 1 total leases, 0 expired leases, 1 workers.Unfinished lease target: 1 leases, I have 1 unfinished leases. Finished leases target is 1 and I have 0 finished leases. I will take 0 leases in total.
2021-04-05 13:43:15.248  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : TakeLeases took 0 seconds.
2021-04-05 13:43:35.322  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : Worker Test-application-lMtQuWkZeFmq+ saw 1 total leases, 0 expired leases, 1 workers.Unfinished lease target: 1 leases, I have 1 unfinished leases. Finished leases target is 1 and I have 0 finished leases. I will take 0 leases in total.
2021-04-05 13:43:35.323  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : TakeLeases took 0 seconds.
2021-04-05 13:43:55.399  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : Worker Test-application-lMtQuWkZeFmq+ saw 1 total leases, 0 expired leases, 1 workers.Unfinished lease target: 1 leases, I have 1 unfinished leases. Finished leases target is 1 and I have 0 finished leases. I will take 0 leases in total.
2021-04-05 13:43:55.399  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : TakeLeases took 0 seconds.
2021-04-05 13:44:09.937  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.k.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker  : Current stream shard assignments: shardId-00000001617600000000-000000000000
2021-04-05 13:44:09.937  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.k.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker  : Sleeping ...
2021-04-05 13:44:15.470  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : Worker Test-application-lMtQuWkZeFmq+ saw 1 total leases, 0 expired leases, 1 workers.Unfinished lease target: 1 leases, I have 1 unfinished leases. Finished leases target is 1 and I have 0 finished leases. I will take 0 leases in total.
2021-04-05 13:44:15.470  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : TakeLeases took 0 seconds.
2021-04-05 13:44:35.550  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : Worker Test-application-lMtQuWkZeFmq+ saw 1 total leases, 0 expired leases, 1 workers.Unfinished lease target: 1 leases, I have 1 unfinished leases. Finished leases target is 1 and I have 0 finished leases. I will take 0 leases in total.
2021-04-05 13:44:35.551  INFO 11414 --- [oordinator-0000] c.a.s.d.s.leases.StreamsLeaseTaker       : TakeLeases took 0 seconds.
2021-04-05 13:44:38.723  INFO 11414 --- [o-auto-1-exec-5] c.c.u.d.s.controller.TestItemController  : Getting itemNumber=23456
2021-04-05 13:44:41.374  INFO 11414 --- [o-auto-1-exec-5] c.c.u.d.s.controller.TestItemController  : Item=TestItem{itemNumber='23456', description='A doo', price=10.99}
```

## Config Info

- dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter: 1.5.2
- amazon-kinesis-client: 1.13.3
- junit-jupiter-api: 5.6.0
- junit-jupiter: 1.15.2
- localstack: 1.15.2
- localstack: 0.12.9
- localstack-utils: 0.2.10
- aws-java-sdk-dynamodb: 1.11.858
- spring-boot-starter-web: 2.3.3.RELEASE
- spring data dynamodb (from boostchicken fork): 5.2.5
- MacOS Catalina: 10.15.7
- Java: 15.0.2
- Docker:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.9
 Version:           20.10.5
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        55c4c88
 Built:             Tue Mar  2 20:13:00 2021
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       363e9a8
  Built:            Tue Mar  2 20:15:47 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
 Kubernetes:
  Version:          Unknown
  StackAPI:         Unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

After many hours of playing with this I *finally* noticed this message

> 2021-04-05 13:42:24.954  INFO 11414 --- [cessingThread-0] c.a.s.k.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker  : Initialization complete. Starting worker loop.

After looking at this a while it became obvious that when using Testcontainer/Localstack it takes 10 seconds for the worker to become initialized and "ready". This was easy enough to solve as the *com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker* has a state change listener, so I could setup a listener to determine when Localstack was ready and then allow the code to continue.

### Final Issues

Sadly this did not resolve the problem completely, turns out that the DynamoDb streams implementation in Testcontainer/Localstack is extremely slow. By that I mean would create/delete or modify a record it it was taking upwards of 7 seconds for the shard processor to get the updates. So here I ended up putting a 10 second sleep between the time that I deleted the item and before I checked to verify the item was actually removed.

### Conclusion

So this turned out to be a timing issue, Testconatiners/Localstack is just very slow pushing the data to the shards (at least compared to the same exact code run against DynamoDb and DynamoDb Streams).